# Code::Blocks issues to run

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

When I want to run Code::Blocks, suddenly this box appears:

[image]

And I can't execute it. Does someone have any solution? There does not exist any document called `roaming\codeBlocks`.

Comment: This has an answer on the Code::Blocks forum.  Close CodeBlocks, find the empty default.conf file and delete it. http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=15643.0

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: That sounds like an _answer_ to me.

Comment: Note that the forum posts implies this was fixed three years ago. You should update your Code::Blocks installation to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This has an answer on the Code::Blocks forum:

- Close CodeBlocks
- Find the empty default.conf file, delete it
- Restart to regenerate the file

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=15643.0

As @Lightness notes, this should be a resolved issue. You might want to update your Blocks.